# Why does Ace say "You've got to give them the key to everything that's yours?"

Tags: analysis, dialogue, casino

> Ace Rothstein: [voice-over] When you love someone, you've gotta trust
>   them. There's no other way. You've got to give them the key to
>   everything that's yours. Otherwise, what's the point? And for a while,
>   I believed, that's the kind of love I had.  [Ace's car explodes]

Why does he say that? What does this mean?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're looking for here.  As this currently reads it seems you're looking more for relationship advice rather than plot explanation or something related to the movie itself.

Comment: When he says "give them the key to everything that's yours" he doesn't **literally** mean give them all your keys.  He means it metaphorically - you have to let them in to your heart, to trust them - to give them the key to YOU.

Comment: It would be great if you could rephrase the question to fit the context of the movie.  This is a great movie and would be an interesting question if it would be addressing the movie.  I would love to have this question reopened :)

Comment: i edited the question... Hope it fits the criteria.... stack exchange is bit of unfriendly to newbie... lots of down vote .. demoralising put on hold thing... @steelersquirrel  thanks btw

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry if you felt that anyone was being unfriendly to you.  I really try and help encourage new users rather than down vote them.  I'm sorry that you had this experience.  Thank you for editing your question.  I am voting to have it reopened.  Please don't let this experience deter you from the site.  This is still an interesting question, especially given the fact that we know the type of person that Ace's wife was!  Thank you for your participation :)

Comment: @Leon So sorry for your initial experience but issue was your question was off topic in it's first form but now it's perfectly fine. People do downvote off topic question but it's good that you acted upon the feedback, +1.